# Apache Drill Hbase Query - Audit Columns

Tags: apache-drill

How can I write queries to extract data on condition based on audit columns like TimeRange, etc.

I am actually looking to filter data based on timestamp i.e. basically extracting data for a specific version

Answer (score 0):

As per [Write Drill query output to csv (or some other format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014910/write-drill-query-output-to-csv-or-some-other-format/31122030#31122030)

```
use dfs.tmp; 
alter session set `store.format`='csv';
create table dfs.tmp.my_output as select * from cp.`employee.json`;
```