# Load data from Drill table into Hive Table

Tags: sql, hive, apache-drill

I have created a table using Drill and it is located at

```
/user/abc/drill/Drilltable.
```

Now I would like to load the data from DrillTable into HiveTable which is located at path

```
/user/hive/warehouse/userxyz.db
```

I am using below statement to load data

```
INSERT INTO TABLE HiveTable select *  from DrillTable;
```

I get the error

> Table not found

and I am bit confused how to let Hive know the path of Drill table.

What would be the right way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Hive might be confused about the schema of the drill data as well as the location. If you're willing to experiment, try something like this:

1. Store the data in a Drill format you can model in Hive, CSV for example, as described [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31122030/2747300).
2. In Hive, create an external table that defines the schema and location of the textual data. You can then convert the external table to a managed table (optional). [For example ...](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.1/using-hiveql/content/hive_create_an_external_table.html).