# Multi line command (to export .csv) not working in Apache Drill (web interface)

Tags: export-to-csv, apache-drill

I am trying to use Apache Drill to export a .csv file. [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014910/write-drill-query-output-to-csv-or-some-other-format) indicated that this is achieved by:

```
use dfs.tmp; 
alter session set `store.format`='csv';
create table dfs.tmp.my_output as select * from cp.`employee.json`;
```

I tried running this block (of three commands) simultaneously in the Apache Drill web interface but got the error bellow. It somehow is not recognizing the `;` or not taking multiple commands.

I also tried running each line separately, without the `;` but the changes of the two commands did not persist (and the export command (3rd command) deafauted back to exporting a parquet file (the set default)).

How can I run this in Drill?

```
Query Failed: An Error Occurred 
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: PARSE ERROR: Encountered ";" at line 1, column 12. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "." ... "[" ... SQL Query use dfs.tmp; ^ alter session set `store.format`='csv'; create table dfs.tmp.`elos_cnis` as select * from dfs.tmp.`/bases_parquet/elos_cnis` [Error Id: 00493fbe-924e-43e9-a684-f7d1abfed04e on sbsb35.ipea.gov.br:31010] (org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParseException) Encountered ";" at line 1, column 12. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "." ... "[" ... org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.parser.impl.DrillParserImpl.convertException():391 org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.parser.impl.DrillParserImpl.normalizeException():121 org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseStmt():149 org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.SqlConverter.parse():157 org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getQueryPlan():104 org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getPlan():79 org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.runSQL():1017 org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.run():289 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker():1142 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run():617 java.lang.Thread.run():748 Caused By (org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.parser.impl.ParseException) Encountered ";" at line 1, column 12. Was expecting one of: <EOF> "." ... "[" ... org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.parser.impl.DrillParserImpl.generateParseException():17963 org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.parser.impl.DrillParserImpl.jj_consume_token():17792 org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.parser.impl.DrillParserImpl.SqlStmtEof():861 org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.parser.impl.DrillParserImpl.parseSqlStmtEof():180 org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.parser.impl.DrillParserWithCompoundIdConverter.parseSqlStmtEof():59 org.apache.calcite.sql.parser.SqlParser.parseStmt():142 org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.SqlConverter.parse():157 org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getQueryPlan():104 org.apache.drill.exec.planner.sql.DrillSqlWorker.getPlan():79 org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.runSQL():1017 org.apache.drill.exec.work.foreman.Foreman.run():289 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker():1142 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run():617 java.lang.Thread.run():748
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drill Web-UI does not support submitting multiple queries within the same query page. Please try using SqlLine or submit in Web-UI one-by-one

```
alter system set `store.format`='csv';
```

query to set `store.format` at the system level, since Web-UI does not store session by default and after that submit the following query

```
create table dfs.tmp.my_output as select * from cp.`employee.json`;
```